# How to convert ndarry to cpp vector array

Tags: python, c++, arrays, nullptr, cppyy

I'm running cpp code in python using cppyy module.
At some point I need to pass array to the CPP function. When I pass numpy array I get following error.

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-331df36ad536> in <module>
----> 1 getPeakall(2, input_array, len(input_array))

ValueError: PeaksData ::getPeakall(int argc, double* argv, int len) =>
    ValueError: nullptr result where temporary expected
```

I guess I need to need to convert ndarray to CPP vector array or pointer array and then pass as an input to CPP function.
Pleas help!!

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Code line:
cppyy.gbl.getPeakall(2, input_array, len(input_array))

Comment: What is the type of `input_array` and is it flat/contiguous? You *can* force passing non-contiguous numpy arrays through a `double*`, but as a rule, numpy will not allow it unless explicitly told (through casting) that you accept the consequences.